# Angular2 - asp.core - Fails to bind directives when routing to specific url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I have spent waaay to much time on this and about to wave the white flag.

My app works fine when run from index.html, I lazy load a feature which uses bindings to apply styling for testing purposes.

However if I go directly to the url I get exception

> "Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise):
>   TypeError: Cannot set property 'padding' of undefined".

What makes things harder is that the highlight directive works fine, its only my label directive that does not bind. If I remove the label attribute from my html the page loads fine. I am really struggling to find the issue causing this.

**app module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './components/hero/hero-detail.component';
import { HeroListComponent } from './components/hero/hero-list.component';
import { HeroService } from './components/hero/hero.service';
import { HeroDashboardComponent } from './components/hero/hero-dashboard.component';
import { HeroMainComponent } from './components/hero/hero-main.component';
import { HeroFormComponent } from './components/form/hero-form.component';

import { ReactiveFormModule } from './components/form-reactive/form-reactive.module';

import { CoreModule } from './components/core/core.module';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routes'

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        CoreModule,
        ReactiveFormModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent, 
        HeroDetailComponent,
        HeroListComponent,
        HeroDashboardComponent,
        HeroMainComponent,
        HeroFormComponent
    ],
    providers: [HeroService]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './components/hero/hero-detail.component';
import { HeroListComponent } from './components/hero/hero-list.component';
import { HeroDashboardComponent } from './components/hero/hero-dashboard.component';
import { HeroMainComponent } from './components/hero/hero-main.component';
import { HeroFormComponent } from './components/form/hero-form.component';    

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'hero/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
    { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
    {
        path: 'hero', component: HeroMainComponent, children:
        [
            { path: '', component: HeroListComponent }, // url: hero/
            { path: 'dashboard', component: HeroDashboardComponent },
            { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
        ]
    },
    { path: 'form', component: HeroFormComponent },
    { path: 'form-reactive', loadChildren: () => { return Promise.resolve(require('./components/form-reactive/form-reactive.module')['ReactiveFormModule']) }},
    { path: 'core-tracking', loadChildren: () => { return Promise.resolve(require('./components/core/core.module')['CoreModule']); } },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

core-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CoreTrackingMainComponent } from './coreTrackingMain.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
        { path: '', component: CoreTrackingMainComponent }
    ])],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ContactRoutingModule { }
```

core.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ContactRoutingModule } from './core-routing.module';

import { CoreTrackingMainComponent } from './coreTrackingMain.component';
import { CoreTrackingCriteriaComponent } from './coreTrackingCriteria.component';
import { CriteriaLabelDirective } from './coreCriteriaLabel.directive';
import { HighlightDirective } from './coreCriteriaHighlight.directive';


@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ContactRoutingModule],
    declarations: [
        CoreTrackingMainComponent,
        CoreTrackingCriteriaComponent,
        CriteriaLabelDirective,
        HighlightDirective,
    ],
    exports: [
        CoreTrackingMainComponent,
        CoreTrackingCriteriaComponent
    ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

coreCriteriaLabel.directive.ts

```
    import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({ selector: '[myLabel]' })

    export class CriteriaLabelDirective {
        constructor(el: ElementRef) {
            el.nativeElement.style.padding = '6px 0';
}
        }
```

coreCriteriaHighlight.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({ selector: '[myHighlight]' })

export class HighlightDirective {
    @Input('myHighlight') highlightColor: string;
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
        this.highlight(this.highlightColor || 'red');
    }
    @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
        this.highlight(null);
    }
    private highlight(color: string) {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

coreTrackingCriteria.component.html

```
<h2>Core Tracking Criteria</h2>
<div class="criteria-container col-xs-12">
    <form [formGroup]="trackingForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label [myHighlight]="color" class="control-label col-xs-4">Reader Organization</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input class="form-control" formControlName="readerOrg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label [myLabel] class="control-label col-xs-4">Location</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input class="form-control" formControlName="location">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

coreTrackingCriteria.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'core-criteria',
    templateUrl: './coreTrackingCriteria.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./coreTrackingCriteria.component.css']
})
export class CoreTrackingCriteriaComponent {

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.createForm();
    }

    color: string = 'blue';

    trackingForm: FormGroup;

    createForm() {
        this.trackingForm = this.fb.group({
            readerOrg: ['', Validators.required],
            location: ['', Validators.required],
        });
    }

}
```

> Update

Implement ngOnInit() rather than using the constructor in the directive. Still causes the same issue

coreCriteriaLabel.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myLabel]' })

export class CriteriaLabelDirective implements OnInit {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.padding = '6px 0';
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the html where this directive is used?

Comment: Where and how is `myLabel` be used? Have you tried to move `el.nativeElement.style.padding = '6px 0';` to `ngOnInit()` or `ngAfterContentInit()` (shouldn't be necessary though)?

Comment: Updated my post, @günter-zöchbauer should I apply ngOnInit() to my directive, I thought these hooks were normally applied to components

Comment: A component is a directive with a view. A directive can have inputs, therefore  `ngOnChange()`, `ngOnInit()` are required lifecycle methods also for directives. A directive is quite similar to a component with a template `<ng-content></ng-content>`, therefore `ngAfterContentInit()` is also working AFAIK, I'm also quite sure `ngAfterViewInit()` is called, even when a directive doesn't have a view. Therefore I'd say it's definitely worth a try.

Comment: Updated my post, no causing the same issue after adding ngOnInit(). Just removed the @HostListener interface on my Highlight Directive and I had the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally got my directive.

1. I used the Renderer class rather than attaching directly to the
   elements nativeElement.
2. I also needed to include the @Input
   decorator for the app to compile properly.

   Any explanation for the reasons for this behavior would be appreciated.

   ```
   import { Directive, Renderer, ElementRef, Input,  } from '@angular/core';
   @Directive({ selector: '[myLabel]' })

   export class CriteriaLabelDirective  {
       @Input('myLabel') myLabel;
       constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private el: ElementRef) {
               this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'padding', '6px 0');
       }
   }
   ```